# Trigger PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql-12

Is it possible in Postgresql 12 to set up master/slave servers so that the replication has to be manually triggered? The database is large, so it’s not feasible to dump and import. The optimal would be if there was a way to do this without any external tools or modules.

Comment: No, both replication solutions (streaming, logical) work completely automatically.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Thanks!